# Changing a sentence to be more formal

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

How can I write the following sentence in a more formal way?

> you can classify your questions from easy to strong.

Comment: *You can rate your questions from easy to difficult.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"strong" is not the right word here.  A long password is "strong" because it's hard to hack, but a question isn't "strong" if you expect that many people won't get the right answer.  It's hard or difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this could be a preferred way to say -

> *You can sort your questions from easy to hard.*